# Are Apache and MySQL multithreaded applications?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, apache, operating-system

I was wondering if the default installations of *Apache* and *MySQL* on *Windows/Linux* are multithreaded or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how to look at it.

*MySQL* allows you to run multiple threads at the same time (this comes to available *CPU/RAM* resources), but it won't allow you to run a single query using multiple threads.

*Apache* is multithreaded, this is the only way how the web application server could respond to multiple requests from different clients.

Comment: Ok so now I usually run drupal. A lot of queries are run to display a single page. but then those wont be multi threaded right?

Comment: @AnuragAshok That is not always true. I don't know Drupal, but I often create pages that make several Ajax calls to load subcontent. These separate requests will run on different threads.

Comment: Your answer is correct but your statement about multithread is wrong.
Multithread is not the only way to deal with the concurrent connection. We have Node.JS that actually is single thread (some people will argue, but it actually is single thread), but it can handle multiple request just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *Apache* and *MySQL* multithreaded.

By the way, they run as a **single process** on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Servers have to be able to deal with many connections at once. Everything has to be on asynchronous threads.