# Does php-apache connect to mysql in a multithreaded manner

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, apache

This question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717934/are-apache-and-mysql-multithreaded-applications), but the question and answers did not have enough detail to satisfy me.

I run a website using php5 on apache2 which connects to a mysql database using `mysql_connect()` without the `new_link` argument being set. This function is called for each new browser-request and the link it returns is stored in a php variable which dies when the request is complete.

Now say that one user requests some data which takes mysql a while to select (ie no table writes occur here) - say it takes 10 seconds. Assume for the sake of argument that for now I am stuck with this query-time and it cannot be made shorter. I want to know what will happen to the other users of the site during this 10 second period. The tables used for this 10 second query are not written to at this time of day, so mysql does not block other operations due to the 10-second query.

Will they be able to complete requests to the database without having to wait for the 10 second query to finish? I think this depends on a few things - mysql being multithreaded, php-apache being multithreaded and actually using a new thread to create a new database connection for each new user, and also the server resources (CPU, RAM, disk-reads, etc).

It is my understanding that php-apache (I'm not interested in php-cli here) will indeed run with multiple threads and create a new connection to mysql in each thread. It will not re-use existing connections, as this would block the second user of the connection until the first user of the connection had finished. I would also assume that so long as mysql is not hitting any rate limits while executing to 10-second query (eg while disk-io is maxed out then some RAM and CPU are free for other threads) then other users will indeed be able to complete requests to the database and continue using the site (maybe slower than usual).

Please could someone confirm/deny the above. A link which explains this in detail would also be very welcome.

Comment: The multi threading bit has been answered in the question linked by you. Whether executing a query blocks another query is a different question. A query may lock tables / records, which may affect other queries.

Comment: i don't think the multithreading part has been answered. the answer says, "MYSQL allows you to run multiple threads at the same time", it doesn't say whether you have to use forks in php to make this happen or whether it happens automatically. i will add more details to the question to explain why there is no table locking.

Comment: php-apache will use whatever scheme httpd is using. If it's using threads, it will use threads. If it's using processes, it will use processes.

Comment: Mysql runs in its own process(es),  independently from php and the webserver. Therfore, forking in php code cannot have any impact on how many processes / threads , mysql uses. The connection type (persistent vs temporary) will affect this.